# Is there any basic tutorial on how to compile software from source under windows

Tags: qt

I'm a beginner on open source world.

I can compile my own C++ code in VS 2015. but, I have little knowledge about compiling open source code. I can't even find a project file of that.

Anyway, I'd like to compile Sigil 0.9.4 version from source. My system is Windows 10 64 bit, and Qt 5.6.0 is installed. I've been looking for any basic guide for that but I haven't found yet.

I have downloaded a source code zip file from the link
https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/releases

And I have no idea what's the difference between Sigil-0.9.4-Code.zip and Source code (zip).
Which one should I download to compile?

Intuitively, I used 'importing project' in Qt but I get message 'no rule to make target all. stop'

[image]
Any instructions for that?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 5):

For compilation you will need to use [CMake](https://cmake.org/). I recommend going through their web-site and read about it.

If you look at the source repository of the software you are trying to build (Sigil), you will see the root folder contains [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt). This is the file that will tell `cmake` program how to build and configure the software.

If you are planning to use Qt as your IDE, I recommend to download and install cmake first. Then make sure, [Qt's toolchain is set up properly with the cmake](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-cmake.html). Then all you have to do is to open that `CMakeLists.txt` in Qt (see more details in the aforementioned link). Also, you can find plenty other tutorials on how to use `cmake` to compile your projects.

Hope this will help you get started.

Comment: Glad it helped! Note: the best way to say "thanks" on StackOverflow is to accept (or upvote) the answer that helped to solve your problem ;)